# translate from and transform translate don't match

Tags: svg

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <g transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(135,10,10)"> 
    <polygon points="0,0 10,0 10,10" fill="purple" />
  </g> 
  <g transform="translate(-2.5,11) rotate(135,10,10)"> 
    <polygon points="0,0 4.75,0 4.75,4.75 0,4.75" fill="blue" class="box" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="20 11" to="22 10" dur="5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="135" to="180" dur="5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="1" additive="sum" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

translate from="20 11" for the second polygon doesn't match with transform="translate(0, 0). I want the translation to start from 0,0 but I can't get the from term to match the translate term.

Comment: So I published my animation at https://koreanforkicks.com/ and you can see it at the top left-side, but the pieces of the puzzle/tangram start out from all different directions and not from their transform="translate(x,y)" origins.